# Regarding CPU Utilization in Solaris

Tags: solaris, cpu-usage

I would like to know how to find out the following for a Solaris box:

1. Number of occurrences of CPU
   Utilization at 100%
2. Duration of time
       CPU stayed at 100%

Is there any variant of `sar` command to find this out?

Thank you in advance,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, nearly every individual instruction executed happens at 100% utilization.  :)

But seriously.  You probably don't want to track individual periods of high utilization.  You probably want a statistics aggregation which averages usage over regular time periods, which is all that sar does.

You could install something like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), or if you already have a snmp-counter application like [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) installed somewhere, you could just query values from the Solaris system via SNMP.  Some availability-monitors like [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) are extensible in that they can measure CPU (or other) usages over regular time periods and present that information to you in a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris comes with sar by default. If it's not installed you should be able to get the package off the install media. That should give the info you need.

For a good lightweight, easily installed interface into system performance, search for the "dim_STAT" tool.